# Gitlab pipeline fails when run with prefilled variables but runs when those variables are created manually

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

In .gitlab-ci.yml I have defined prefilled variables using -

```html
variables:
  tenant:
    description: "Enter tenant here"
 
stage:
  - job1
 
build:
  stage: job1
  script:
    cat abcd.yml > deployment.yml
 
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - deployment.yml
```

abcd.yml contains following -

```html
stages:
  - jobxyz
 
.checker: &checker
  rules:
    if $tenant =~ /.+/:
    when: manual
    variables:
      color: blue

job_xyz:
    stage: jobxyz
    extends: .checker
```

Originally when the variable tenant was not present in .gitlab-ci.yml and the variable was created manually while running pipeline it ran successfully. But when I populate it as a prefilled variable it doesn't pass those values to abcd.yml

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "when I populate it as a prefilled variable" -- and how exactly are you doing that? I'm also not clear on how `abcd.yml` is being used at all or how you're "passing" the variable to that file.

Comment: variables:
      tenant:
        description: "Enter tenant here"

Makes it a prefilled variable with blank as default value. When we try to run the pipeline manually we can see this variable already populated.